# Why I am getting extra cells in tableview in swift

Tags: json, swift, tableview

**This is Json response:** **in response i need to show only `oniTaag = 1` contact userName in tableview** how? i am getting `oniTaag = 0` contact userName as label in tableview why?

```
contacts JSON group member
["5555555544": {
oniTaag = 1;
profilePic = "<null>";
tagged = 0;
userId = a398056b39cb4d0fb3ad666b86abe2e1;
userName = "security test";
userType = personal;
}, 
"0000034500": {
oniTaag = 0;
profilePic = "<null>";
tagged = 0;
userId = "<null>";
userName = "<null>";
userType = personal;
}, 
"0000043251": {
oniTaag = 1;
profilePic = "<null>";
tagged = 0;
userId = 835e13f3b16f4d0d84384c4aa4e2c0b5;
userName = "daddy?s dad add";
userType = personal;
}]
```

here `oniTaag = 1` means `true` those contacts only i need to show in tableview.. but here `oniTaag = 0` contact showing label, label in cell, why?

**here is the code:**

```
 import Contacts
 struct ContactDetailsJson {

var userId: String?
var onItag: Bool?
var taggedStat: Bool?
var userName: String?
var phnum: String?

init(userId: String, oniTaag: Bool, tagged: Bool, userName: String, key: String) {

    self.userId = userId
    self.onItag = oniTaag
    self.taggedStat = tagged
    self.userName = userName
    self.phnum = key
}
}

class GroupMembersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var phoneNum: String?
  var contacts = [CNContact]()
 var phNumArray  = [String]()

  var onitag: Bool?
  var userNAme: String?
  var jsonArrayFilter = [ContactDetailsJson]()

@IBOutlet weak var groupMemTableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
     ContactsModel.shared.getLocalContacts {(contact) in
         self.contacts.append(contact!)
         print("all contects \(contact)")
         
         self.phNumArray = self.contacts.flatMap { $0.phoneNumbers }.map { $0.value.stringValue }
         
     }

     self.callPostApi()
}
func callPostApi() {

          let url            = URL(string: "http://filter/taggedusers/")!
          var request        = URLRequest(url: url)
         
          try? request.setMultipartFormData(["contactsList": "\(phNumArray)"], encoding: .utf8)
         
          URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
              if let data = data, let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                  print("contacts JSON group member\(jsonObj)")
                  let phnDict: [String : Any] = (jsonObj as? [String : Any])!

                  for (key, val) in phnDict{

                      let phnum: String = key as? String ?? ""
                      let phKey = val as! [String : Any]
                      let userId = phKey["userId"] as? String
                      let userNam = phKey["userName"]
                      self.taggedStatus = phKey["tagged"] as? Bool
                      self.onitag = phKey["oniTaag"] as? Bool
                      self.userNAme = phKey["userName"] as? String
                      
                      self.jsonArrayFilter.append(ContactDetailsJson(userId: userId ?? "", oniTaag: self.onitag ?? true, tagged: self.taggedStatus ?? true, userName: self.userNAme ?? "", key: phnum))
                  }
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.groupMemTableview.reloadData()
                  }

              }
          }.resume()
      }
      
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return jsonArrayFilter.count
 }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      
           var cell1: GroupMemberTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! GroupMemberTableViewCell
            
            jsonArrayFilter = jsonArrayFilter.filter { ($0.onItag ?? true) }

            let aJson = jsonArrayFilter[indexPath.row]
            
            if aJson.onItag == true{

                    cell1.nameLabel.text = aJson.userName
                    cell1.phnumLabel.text = aJson.phnum
            }
            return cell1
    }
}
```

getting output like below: here i dont need label label cell.. means `oniTaag = 0` cell.. how?

please help me with code.

**edit**: here `let aJson = jsonArrayFilter[indexPath.row]` getting below error

> error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of you use all the array without filtration and this if statement doesn't hit

```
if aJson.onItag == true{ 
    cell1.nameLabel.text = aJson.userName
    cell1.phnumLabel.text = aJson.phnum  
}
```

you get a dummy cell with empty labels for models that has `onItag  = false` you need to filter the array before using it

```
   self.jsonArrayFilter.append(ContactDetailsJson(userId: userId ?? "", oniTaag: self.onitag ?? true, tagged: self.taggedStatus ?? true, userName: self.userNAme ?? "", key: phnum))
}
jsonArrayFilter = jsonArrayFilter.filter { $0.onItag ?? false }
```

Comment: i have edited post with your answer then `let aJson = jsonArrayFilter[indexPath.row]`  error  Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: howcan i filter with my `jsonArrayFilter ` according to my post

Comment: i have updated my post with total code.. including `callPostApi` .. let me know how to filter

Comment: see edit after the for loop and remove it form `cellForRowAt`